# How to install JDK8 on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, openjdk

I needed JDK 8 for Bazel.  I ran `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8*` on a freshly built Ubuntu 16.04.02 machine, but after installation `update-alternatives --config java` show two paths:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

I purged `opensdk-8*` and then installed `apt-get openjdk-9*` but the outcome was the same.

How do I get JDK 8?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Usually you install the openjdk like this:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Maybe this is the problem. You can look this up at
http://openjdk.java.net/install/index.html. 
If you do this you might have fixed this problem. But cant imagine why your command give this result.

Comment: I did this but I got `E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk`.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` first. You need to be connected to the internet.

Answer (score 3):

I installed oracle-jdk8. If you need,

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && sudo apt update
>   sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer

Answer (score 0):

You can install openJDK with below command -

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

OR You can also look at option to install Oracle Java 8. Detailed instructions are updated in the [blog here](https://crunchytechbytz.wordpress.com/2018/06/22/installing-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-18-04/). You can also use below commands for a quick answer -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default

javac -version
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply follow below steps

1. Download JDK 1.8 from https://repo.huaweicloud.com/java/jdk/8u202-b08/jdk-8u202-linux-x64.tar.gz
2. Extract it using tar -xvzf ~/Downloads/jdk-8u202-linux-x64.tar.gz ~/JDK-1.8
3. set JAVA_HOME using command export JAVA_HOME=~/JDK-1.8
4. set PATH using command export PATH=~/JDK-1.8/bin:$PATH

Use below URL for more details
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-manually-install-java-8-on-ubuntu-16-04/